# Financial Analysis with Python - returning Value Error

Tags: python, finance, valueerror

I'm looking to analyze financial data using python. I am using the below function but I continue to run into a value error and I can't figure out how to fix the error

The expected result of this function was to create 5000 portfolios with the selected tickers putting random weight in each asset to construct the portfolios. The next function ('optimal_portfolio') would then optimize those results and I would then plot the efficient frontier.

This is the function:

```
def return_portfolios(expected_returns, cov_matrix):
np.random.seed(1)
port_returns = []
port_volatility = []
stock_weights = []

selected = (expected_returns.axes)[0]
#this specifies the number of random portfolios generated  
num_assets = len(selected) 
num_portfolios = 5000

for single_portfolio in range(num_portfolios):
weights = np.random.random(num_assets)
weights /= np.sum(weights)
returns = np.dot(weights, expected_returns)
volatility = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights)))
port_returns.append(returns)
port_volatility.append(volatility)
stock_weights.append(weights)

portfolio = {'Returns': port_returns,
             'Volatility': port_volatility}

for counter,symbol in enumerate(selected):
portfolio[symbol +' Weight'] = [Weight[counter] for Weight in stock_weights]

df = pd.DataFrame(portfolio)

column_order = ['Returns', 'Volatility'] + [stock+' Weight' for stock in selected]

df = df[column_order]

return df


def optimal_portfolio(returns):
n = returns.shape[1]
returns = np.transpose(returns.values)

N = 10
mus = [10**(5.0 * t/N - 1.0) for t in range(N)]

# Convert to cvxopt matrices
S = opt.matrix(np.cov(returns))
pbar = opt.matrix(np.mean(returns, axis=1))

# Create constraint matrices
G = -opt.matrix(np.eye(n))   # negative n x n identity matrix
h = opt.matrix(0.0, (n ,1))
A = opt.matrix(1.0, (1, n))
b = opt.matrix(1.0)

# Calculate efficient frontier weights using quadratic programming
portfolios = [solvers.qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus]

## CALCULATE RISKS AND RETURNS FOR FRONTIER
returns = [blas.dot(pbar, x) for x in portfolios]
risks = [np.sqrt(blas.dot(x, S*x)) for x in portfolios]
## CALCULATE THE 2ND DEGREE POLYNOMIAL OF THE FRONTIER CURVE
m1 = np.polyfit(returns, risks, 2)
x1 = np.sqrt(m1[2] / m1[0])
# CALCULATE THE OPTIMAL PORTFOLIO
wt = solvers.qp(opt.matrix(x1 * S), -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x']
return np.asarray(wt), returns, risks
```

and this is the error I get when I call `weights, returns, risks = optimal_portfolio(stock_data_daily_returns[1:])`:

```
  pcost       dcost       gap    pres   dres
   0:      nan      nan  nan    nan    nan
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-32-9ec61d3ea2bf> in <module>
  ----> 1 weights, returns, risks = optimal_portfolio(stock_data_daily_returns[1:])

  <ipython-input-29-2a6004abd0c3> in optimal_portfolio(returns)
    17 
    18     # Calculate efficient frontier weights using quadratic programming
  ---> 19     portfolios = [solvers.qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus]
    20 
    21     ## CALCULATE RISKS AND RETURNS FOR FRONTIER

     <ipython-input-29-2a6004abd0c3> in <listcomp>(.0)
    17 
    18     # Calculate efficient frontier weights using quadratic programming
  ---> 19     portfolios = [solvers.qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus]
    20 
    21     ## CALCULATE RISKS AND RETURNS FOR FRONTIER

  c:\users\tylev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\coneprog.py in qp(P,    q, G, h, A, b, solver, kktsolver, initvals, **kwargs)
    4483             'residual as dual infeasibility certificate': dinfres}
    4484 
 -> 4485     return coneqp(P, q, G, h, None, A,  b, initvals, kktsolver = kktsolver, options = options)

    c:\users\tylev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\coneprog.py in coneqp(P, q, G, h, dims, A, b, initvals, kktsolver, xnewcopy, xdot, xaxpy, xscal, ynewcopy, ydot, yaxpy, yscal, **kwargs)
    2241         # lmbdasq = lambda o lambda.
    2242 
 -> 2243         if iters == 0:  W = misc.compute_scaling(s, z, lmbda, dims)
    2244         misc.ssqr(lmbdasq, lmbda, dims)
    2245 

    c:\users\tylev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\misc.py in       compute_scaling(s, z, lmbda, dims, mnl)
    283 
    284     m = dims['l']
--> 285     W['d'] = base.sqrt( base.div( s[mnl:mnl+m], z[mnl:mnl+m] ))
    286     W['di'] = W['d']**-1
    287     lmbda[mnl:mnl+m] = base.sqrt( base.mul( s[mnl:mnl+m], z[mnl:mnl+m] ) )

    ValueError: domain error
```

If someone could give me some advice I'd really appreciate it since nothing I try seems to fix it

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, your code is not indented properly and your imports are missing!

Answer (score 0):

The traceback that you posted points at this line:

```py
portfolios = [solvers.qp(mu*S, -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for mu in mus]
```

which apparently uses some quadratic programming solver.

One of the calls in this loop causes the library to fail at this line:

```py
--> 285     W['d'] = base.sqrt( base.div( s[mnl:mnl+m], z[mnl:mnl+m] ))
```

The `domain error` is most likely raised because the function tries to take the square root of a **negative number**.

I would start with checking all the inputs to `solvers.qp()` and making sure that they make (mathematical) sense.